# DB2 SQL MAX() SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, db2

```
DATA:
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0002  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0007  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0012  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0017  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0022  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0027  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0032  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0037  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0042  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0047  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0052  
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0057  
0407340207,0083,0001,0000000,0004  
0407340207,0083,0001,0000000,0009  
0407340207,0083,0001,0000000,0014  
0407340207,0083,0001,0000000,0019  
0407340207,0083,0001,0000000,0024
```

I got the above data and want to do a subquery using max to only get the two row 
Eg…

```
0407340207,0001,0001,0000000,0057  
0407340207,0083,0001,0000000,0024
```

What am I doing incorrect

```
SELECT                                                                
    BEI.COLUMN1,                                                    
    BEI.COLUMN2,                                                       
    BEI.COLUMN3,                                                  
    BEI.COLUMN4                                                      
    AND BEI.COLUMN5 = (SELECT MAX(MAXBEI.COLUMN5)                 
    FROM DWHRTB01.BEN_ELEM_INFO BEI                                       
    WHERE BEI.FK_CHNG_DT <= '2014-03-31'                                  
    AND BEI.COLUMN2 IN (01, 80, 81, 83, 84, 105, 106, 107, 108, 137, 138)  
    AND BEI.COLUMN5 = (SELECT MAX(MAXBEI.COLUMN5)                 
    FROM DWHRTB01.BEN_ELEM_INFO MAXBEI                                 
    WHERE (BEI.COLUMN1 = MAXBEI.COLUMN1)                             
    AND (BEI.COLUMN2 = MAXBEI.COLUMN2)                                   
    AND (BEI.COLUMN3 = MAXBEI.COLUMN3)                         
    AND BEI.FK_CHNG_DT <= '2014-03-31'                                 
    AND BEI.COLUMN2 IN (01, 80, 81, 83, 84, 105, 106, 107, 108, 137, 138))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do... "using max to only get the two row" does not explain the logic of your goal.  We have no idea how to help

Comment: Well, first off, you appear to have a syntax error in your code (`BEI.COLUMN4 AND BEI.COLUMN5`).  Did the system not return you an error pointing this out?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple queries:

```
SELECT                                                                
    BEI.COLUMN1,                                                    
    BEI.COLUMN2,                                                       
    BEI.COLUMN3,                                                  
    BEI.COLUMN4,
    MAX( BEI.COLUMN5 )
FROM DWHRTB01.BEN_ELEM_INFO BEI
GROUP BY
    BEI.COLUMN1,                                                    
    BEI.COLUMN2,                                                       
    BEI.COLUMN3,                                                  
    BEI.COLUMN4
```